# HTML DOM w3schools clarification

Tags: html, dom

just reading the W3schools HTML DOM tutorial. There's a paragraph that makes no sense to me.

The bit that doesn't make sense to me is:

> A common error in DOM processing is to expect an element node to contain text.
>
> However, the text of an element node is stored in a text node.
>
> In this example: `<title>DOM Tutorial</title>`, the element node `<title>`, holds a text node with the value "DOM Tutorial".
>
> "DOM Tutorial" is **not** the value of the `<title>` element!
>
> However, in the HTML DOM the value of the text node can be accessed by the innerHTML property.

Ok, what? That sounds exactly the opposite of what I though. 
Thanks

Comment: What exactly about this doesn't make sense to you, can you clarify?

Comment: W3Schools is often considered to be a poor quality resource (see http://www.w3fools.com for more detail on this). I agree with you that the text you've posted could be confusing (it is accurate, but poorly written). I would suggest finding a different site to learn from.

Comment: I thought they were saying the title was not the title effectively :/ I'm not a fan of W3Schools to be honest, and after this I'll be giving them a wider berth than usual :)

Comment: the w3Fools site has some excellent resources on it, thanks for that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a markup document is converted into a DOM, you end up with a tree of nodes.

There are several types of nodes, including elements, text and comments.

Nodes have properties. e.g. an HTMLInputNode will have a `value` property that maps on to its current value. Any HTMLElementNode will have a `style` property through which the CSS properties defined via the `style` attribute can be accessed. Likewise, it will also have a `className` property that maps onto the `class` attribute.

When you have `<title>DOM Tutorial</title>` you have a HTMLTitleNode containing a TextNode. To get the text `DOM Tutorial` you should access the TextNode and then read its `data` property.

```
myTitle.firstChild.data
```

And then W3Schools muddies the water by mentioning `innerHTML`.

`innerHTML` is a property (although not a standard DOM property (I think HTML 5 is in the process of defining it)) of HTMLElementNodes which gives you a serialisation of the HTML contents of an element (but not the element itself).

Since there is only a TextNode inside a title element, you end up with plain text there.

Comment: Gotcha, that was what was confusing me. I thought they were trying to say "The title node is not the title node" :/